# Multiple insert point org source code insert

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-babel

I know that we can customize the source code expansion `<s TAB` using something like this

`(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
             '("s" "#+BEGIN_SRC ? :results raw replace drawer hline: yes\n\n#+END_SRC"))`

This would expand into something like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC <my cursor here>  :results raw replace drawer hline: yes

#+END_SRC
```

My cursor would be at the `<my cursor here>` so I can write name of the source code, e.g C, Python, bash...etc.

I would like to add another "jump point" so I can have something like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC <my cursor here>  :results raw replace drawer hline: yes
<next cursor here>
#+END_SRC
```

So, I can TAB after typing the type of the code and start writing right away. Is it possible to do this? I tried to add a second `?` but it doesnt work.

`(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
             '("s" "#+BEGIN_SRC ? :results raw replace drawer hline: yes\n?\n#+END_SRC"))`

This is what I got after adding a second `?`.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ?  :results raw replace drawer hline: yes
<cursor is here>
#+END_SRC
```

So, the first `?` is skipped entirely.